# Android GridView, AsyncTask and screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gridview, android-asynctask

i have a problem with handling screen rotation and `AsyncTask` in my activity.
Here's the problem:
I have a `MainActivity` which has inside a `PostersFragment`, who manages the layout. Inside it there is a `GridView` to populate with some images fetched by an `AsyncTask`.
When i rotate the device it messess up, and i can see an old `GridView` behind the actual `GridView`. 

 It surely is a problem bound to recreation of the activity, i googled a lot and found the `setRetainInstance(true)` method, i tried to call it in my fragment but nothing changed.
Here's the `MainActivity` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private final String POSTERSFRAGMENT_TAG ="PFTG";
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, new PostersFragment(), POSTERSFRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
    String[] drawerChoices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_choices_array);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerChoices));
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_toolbar);
    if(toolbar!=null){
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawer,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };
    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        String x =parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        if(x.equals(getString(R.string.trending_drawer_option))) {
            PostersFragment fragment = new PostersFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerListView);
        }
        if(x.equals(getString(R.string.bookmarked_drawer_option))){
            BookmarksFragment fragment = new BookmarksFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerListView);
        }
        if(x.equals(getString(R.string.settings_drawer_option))){
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerListView);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListView);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

}

And the `PostersFragment` code:

```
public class PostersFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

public static final int MAX_PAGES = 50;
public int mPagesLoaded = 0;
private ImageAdapter mImages;
public boolean mIsLoading = false;
public TextView loadingText;
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged;

public PostersFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mImages = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
    loadingText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.loadingTextView);
    loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    spChanged = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            mImages.clear();
            mPagesLoaded=0;
        }
    };

    sharedPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(spChanged);
    initGrid(view);
    startLoading();
    return view;
}

private void startLoading()
{
    if(mPagesLoaded>=MAX_PAGES)
        return;
    if(mIsLoading==true)
        return;

    mIsLoading=true;
    if(loadingText!=null)
        loadingText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new FetchPageTask().execute(mPagesLoaded + 1);
}

private void stopLoading()
{
    if(mIsLoading==false)
        return;

    if(mIsLoading==true)
        mIsLoading=false;

    if(loadingText!=null)
        loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
private void initGrid(View view)
{
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    if(gridView==null)
        return;

    gridView.setAdapter(mImages);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageAdapter adapter = (ImageAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
            Movie movie = adapter.getItem(position);

            if (movie == null)
                return;

            //intent to be launched
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Movie.EXTRA_MOVIE,movie.toBundle());
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        int lastScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if(lastScreen == totalItemCount)
                startLoading();
        }
    });

}


private class FetchPageTask extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Collection<Movie>> {
    public final String LOG_TAG = FetchPageTask.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected Collection<Movie> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        if (params.length == 0)
            return null;

        int page = params[0];

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String responseJsonStr = null;

        try {
            final String API_BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
            final String API_PARAM_PAGE = "page";
            final String API_PARAM_KEY = "api_key";
            final String API_SORTING = sharedPrefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_sorting_key),getString(R.string.pref_sorting_default_value));

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(API_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendPath(API_SORTING)
                    .appendQueryParameter(API_PARAM_PAGE, String.valueOf(page))
                    .appendQueryParameter(API_PARAM_KEY, getString(R.string.my_api_key))
                    .build();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Query URI: " + builtUri.toString());

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            if (inputStream == null)
                return null;

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(line + "\n");

            if (buffer.length() == 0)
                return null;

            responseJsonStr = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing input stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return fetchMoviesFromJson(responseJsonStr);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can't parse JSON " + responseJsonStr, je);
            return null;
        }

    }


    private Collection<Movie> fetchMoviesFromJson(String jsonStr) throws JSONException {
        final String KEY_MOVIES = "results";

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray movies = json.getJSONArray(KEY_MOVIES);
        ArrayList<Movie> result = new ArrayList<Movie>();

        for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
            result.add(Movie.getMovieFromJson(movies.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Collection<Movie> movies)
    {
        stopLoading();

        mPagesLoaded++;

        mImages.addAll(movies);
    }

}
```

}

How can I prevent it from duplicating? How should i handle the change of configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onCreate` for MainActivity replace this line:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, new PostersFragment(), POSTERSFRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
```

to

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, new PostersFragment(), POSTERSFRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't clarify as to why this is required. The purpose of this check is to see if the fragment is already there. When can we confirm that the fragment is not there? When `savedInstanceState` is `null`.
Initially, the `Bundle` is `null` when the activity is first created. When the device has a configuration change, all activities/fragments are destroyed and recreated, excepting the ones on which `setRetainInstance(true)` has been called. These fragments are not destroyed. They are just attached to the new activity…
When the activity is recreated after the configuration change, the instance of the retained fragment is already present, and the `savedInstanceState` is not `null` as a result of this. Hence, you check if `savedInstanceState == null` and only then proceed to add the fragment to avoid duplicated.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Just one more question.. Why does that work? I have some ideas but i'd like an explaination, for the sake of curiosity and learning

Comment: Edited answer to explain things better. Sorry I didn't explain it the first time. If you didn't get any part of it, don't hesitate to hit back.

Comment: All clear except for one thing. Your solution worked even if i haven't called the `setRetainInstance` (i deleted because, before the question, it was not working). It simply recreate the fragment. Is this because `savedInstanceState` is null again?

Comment: The `setRetainInstance(true)` is what this check safeguards against. By default Android doesn't retain fragments. Fragment life cycle is explained pretty well here : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Yeah I know the lifecycle... So it's just null again right? By the way I added the retain, now it is all perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yup. It is null. Which meant it will proceed to recreate the fragment

Comment: Glad I could help. ;)